# Array replacement on relationship property in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

So, let's say I have relationship r, with property r.myarray:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

and I need to write a query which will replace the items in the array - up to an including an arbitrary member guaranteed to be in the array (let's say 3 in this case) - with another array - let's say:

```
[6,12,13]
```

to get result:

```
[6,12,13,4,5,6,7]
```

I got as far as seeing that you can use RANGE or subset notation for the array (e.g. r.myarray[0..x]) to specify part of the array, and could theoretically do SET to replace the array with the first array plus the second subset (r.myarray[x..r.myarray.length], or something like that).  I am about half a mile from a complete answer here, though.

**edit**: Final, interpolat-able query:

```
START r=relationship(726)
SET r.myarray = [1,2,3,4] + filter(y in r.ancestors where NOT (y IN [718]));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Range probably isn't what you want.  `Range` produces a collection of numbers.  It's good for looping, like if you want to go through all the numbers from 1-10, but it's not that useful with other array indexes.  You probably want a combination of the `+` operator on collections, index operations, with possibly a dash of `extract` and `filter`.  Combining those will let you do basically whatever you like.  Here are some examples of the things you can do.  I'm using a `WITH` clause just to show a data sample, you could of course do this on any node property:

```
/* Return only the first three items */
with [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] as arr return arr[0..3];

/* Cut out the 4th item, otherwise return everything */
with [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] as arr return arr[0..3] + arr[4..];

/* Return only the even numbers */
with [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] as arr 
return filter(y in 
     extract(x in arr | case when (x % 2 = 0) then x end) where y > 0);
```

Comment: But how do I do either an array difference, or find the index of the last unacceptable item (3) in the array?

Comment: I tried this: START r=relationship(726)
return filter(y in r.myarray where (y NOT IN [718]));   but it gives me an error that "N" in "NOT" was unexpected.

Comment: Ah - where NOT (y in [718]).  Got it!